# CNContactPickerViewController issue on simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9

I am upgrading framework from AddressBook to Contact but I am having issue related to displaying it. I am using iOS 9 and trying in simulator.

The error I am facing is :-

> [CNUI ERROR] Contact picker delayed appearance timed out - YES

It is working fine on device.

Anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 10 beta 4

Answer (score 0):

Same for me after going from Xcode-beta 7 to Xcode 7.
I did a Reset Content and Settings... and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the thread issue,I advise you to refresh you UI in main thread,there is a sample like:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

```
    CNContactViewController *vc = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:contact];
    vc.displayedPropertyKeys =@[CNContactGivenNameKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactInstantMessageAddressesKey,CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactDatesKey,CNContactUrlAddressesKey,CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```

Comment: NOTE: the `dispatch_async` line should be formatted as code... I tried to submit an edit, but it was too "small".